# spark scala 'take(10)' operation is taking too long

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I got the following code within my super-simple Spark Scala application:

```
    ...
    val t3 = System.currentTimeMillis
    println("VertexRDD created in " + (t3 - t2) + " ms")
    vertRDD.cache
    val t4 = System.currentTimeMillis
    println("VertexRDD size : "+vertRDD.partitions.size)

    println("VertexRDD cached in " + (t4 - t3) + " ms")
    vertRDD.take(10).foreach(println)
    println("VertexRDD size : "+vertRDD.partitions.size)
    ...
```

I submit my app to EMR Apache Spark cluster with command

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --num-executors 4 --executor-memory 6g --driver-memory 6g --class com.****.TestSpark s3://****.jar
```

With regards to vertRDD - in total there are 250k records there (I'm reading them from the database it is 25Mbyte of data)

. as you can from the code I'm caching RDD few lines before calling this line (#175) below

```
vertRDD.take(10).foreach(println) - line #175 of my app
```

when I'm looking into Spark history I can see that all memory and etc parameters are underutilized - it is barely 60Mb of utilization against several Gigabytes available when this line is getting excuted and what's abnormal that it is being executed for more than 15 minutes always, in some cases it even fails to finish and cluster become 'terminated with errors'.

EMR cluster I'm running it is 1*m5.2xlarge master and 4*m5.2xlarge cores and it in many cases fails! I can't understand WTF!

UPD. After digging in the EMR console I can see that most of time it has garbage collection working

[image]

and I also see that one of 2 workers has been stopped by YARN and this is the log there

```
2021-02-12T20:17:01.404+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 126976K->9341K(147968K)] 126976K->9357K(486912K), 0.0076611 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:02.068+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 136317K->9547K(147968K)] 136333K->9579K(486912K), 0.0079604 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.02, real=0.01 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:02.317+0000: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 80014K->8203K(147968K)] 80046K->8243K(486912K), 0.0047442 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:02.321+0000: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 8203K->0K(147968K)] [ParOldGen: 40K->7927K(195584K)] 8243K->7927K(343552K), [Metaspace: 20290K->20290K(1067008K)], 0.0239302 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:02.885+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 126976K->4351K(195584K)] 134903K->12286K(391168K), 0.0042397 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:03.438+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 195327K->9196K(258560K)] 203262K->17139K(454144K), 0.0076206 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:03.511+0000: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 45869K->4857K(301568K)] 53813K->12800K(497152K), 0.0045228 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:03.515+0000: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 4857K->0K(301568K)] [ParOldGen: 7943K->10963K(274944K)] 12800K->10963K(576512K), [Metaspace: 33870K->33868K(1079296K)], 0.0268540 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:04.638+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 289792K->11772K(301568K)] 300755K->24419K(576512K), 0.0113583 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:07.984+0000: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 273980K->14305K(448000K)] 286626K->27278K(722944K), 0.0115704 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:07.995+0000: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 14305K->0K(448000K)] [ParOldGen: 12972K->23489K(372736K)] 27278K->23489K(820736K), [Metaspace: 53854K->52909K(1099776K)], 0.1044483 secs] [Times: user=0.57 sys=0.02, real=0.10 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:10.207+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 433664K->16376K(462848K)] 457153K->62952K(835584K), 0.0293058 secs] [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.02, real=0.03 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:12.893+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 462840K->27642K(481280K)] 509416K->328728K(854016K), 0.2258796 secs] [Times: user=1.57 sys=0.22, real=0.23 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:13.119+0000: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 27642K->0K(481280K)] [ParOldGen: 301086K->317625K(916480K)] 328728K->317625K(1397760K), [Metaspace: 63821K->63816K(1110016K)], 1.6353318 secs] [Times: user=10.11 sys=0.08, real=1.64 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:15.068+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 453632K->75168K(579584K)] 771257K->523874K(1496064K), 0.0906250 secs] [Times: user=0.59 sys=0.13, real=0.09 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:15.514+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 528800K->2329K(671232K)] 977506K->451043K(1587712K), 0.0152511 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:15.945+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 543001K->76277K(669696K)] 991715K->983751K(1586176K), 0.1116201 secs] [Times: user=0.54 sys=0.35, real=0.12 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:16.057+0000: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 76277K->0K(669696K)] [ParOldGen: 907474K->523576K(1430528K)] 983751K->523576K(2100224K), [Metaspace: 65321K->65321K(1110016K)], 0.9539858 secs] [Times: user=7.26 sys=0.01, real=0.95 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:17.427+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 540672K->7657K(679936K)] 1064248K->531242K(2110464K), 0.0102141 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:17.914+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 637929K->102391K(760832K)] 1161514K->1215807K(2191360K), 0.1063215 secs] [Times: user=0.58 sys=0.20, real=0.10 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:18.020+0000: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 102391K->0K(760832K)] [ParOldGen: 1113416K->454233K(1679872K)] 1215807K->454233K(2440704K), [Metaspace: 65779K->65764K(1112064K)], 0.0906173 secs] [Times: user=0.39 sys=0.00, real=0.09 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:18.733+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 630272K->17588K(888832K)] 1084505K->471830K(2568704K), 0.0175248 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:19.399+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 778420K->29288K(900608K)] 1232662K->483537K(2580480K), 0.0225306 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.03, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:20.012+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 790120K->18446K(962560K)] 1244369K->472704K(2642432K), 0.0210335 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:20.738+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 866830K->18574K(975360K)] 1321088K->472840K(2655232K), 0.0235178 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:21.412+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 866958K->31878K(1034240K)] 1321224K->486152K(2714112K), 0.0243945 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.04, real=0.03 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:22.599+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 964742K->53206K(1047040K)] 1419016K->507488K(2726912K), 0.0283320 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.03, real=0.03 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:23.132+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 986070K->23551K(1113088K)] 1440352K->477840K(2792960K), 0.0177533 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:23.604+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1037311K->28486K(1121280K)] 1491600K->482783K(2801152K), 0.0183161 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.03, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:24.024+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1042246K->36085K(1196032K)] 1496543K->490390K(2875904K), 0.0191460 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.03, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:24.584+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1139957K->50496K(1199616K)] 1594262K->504809K(2879488K), 0.0207042 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:25.046+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1154368K->47787K(1273344K)] 1608681K->502108K(2953216K), 0.0271859 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.03, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:25.520+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1225899K->50015K(1271296K)] 1680220K->504344K(2951168K), 0.0199173 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:26.012+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1228127K->28438K(1347584K)] 1682456K->482776K(3027456K), 0.0222568 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.02, real=0.03 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:26.519+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1290518K->21046K(1350656K)] 1744856K->475392K(3030528K), 0.0208783 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:27.004+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1283126K->51072K(1436672K)] 1737472K->505426K(3116544K), 0.0248668 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.03, real=0.03 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:27.523+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1401216K->49452K(1437184K)] 1855570K->503966K(3117056K), 0.0230231 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:28.038+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1399596K->42078K(1528832K)] 1854110K->496648K(3208704K), 0.0247465 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.02, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:28.670+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1491038K->24493K(1531392K)] 1945608K->479087K(3211264K), 0.0582659 secs] [Times: user=0.15 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:29.633+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1473453K->31079K(1612800K)] 1928047K->486008K(3292672K), 0.0336889 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.02, real=0.04 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:30.843+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1575783K->46063K(1622528K)] 2030712K->501032K(3302400K), 0.0422580 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.01, real=0.04 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:32.433+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1590767K->24292K(1703424K)] 2045736K->480558K(3383296K), 0.0506315 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.02, real=0.05 secs] 
2021-02-12T20:17:34.324+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1659108K->24958K(1710592K)] 2115374K->481281K(3390464K), 0.0576808 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 1710592K, used 1467342K [0x0000000740000000, 0x00000007b2400000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1634816K, 88% used [0x0000000740000000,0x0000000798093f40,0x00000007a3c80000)
  from space 75776K, 32% used [0x00000007a3c80000,0x00000007a54dfb78,0x00000007a8680000)
  to   space 73728K, 0% used [0x00000007adc00000,0x00000007adc00000,0x00000007b2400000)
 ParOldGen       total 1679872K, used 456322K [0x0000000640000000, 0x00000006a6880000, 0x0000000740000000)
  object space 1679872K, 27% used [0x0000000640000000,0x000000065bda0b40,0x00000006a6880000)
 Metaspace       used 71040K, capacity 76834K, committed 76948K, reserved 1116160K
  class space    used 9093K, capacity 9852K, committed 9876K, reserved 1048576K
```

I'm still in WTF mode on why it can't process 25Mb of data...

Comment: One thing is that you have not specified number of cores per executor. When Spark is running on Yarn the default is 1. So there are lots of cores sat idle and your job is running on just one core per executor hence taking a long time. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a huge number of jvm objects on your tasks.  The answer would be in two parts:

1. Decrease paralelism by passing --executor-cores 4 and increase memory --executor-memory 8g
2. pass additional JVM params to you master and executors to change GC to CG1
   --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC"
   --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC"
3. make sure you run on yarn
   --master yarn

Comment: This is actually the command I run and it also stucks on cluster of 40 m5.4xlarge nodes:

Answer (score 0):

Actions like take or count trigger DAG execution which takes some time to execute. You can do the following things to reduce the time:

1. Cache or persist intermediate results
2. If data is small, run it on a single machine
3. Use cloudwatch to Monitor your EMR cluster to check available Yarn memory and container pending ratio during the run, these indicate if your job is lacking resources.